# Q&A on KB Articles using NLP

Tags: nlp, nlp-question-answering

I have a large set of KB Articles (software support), and I am looking for ways to extract answers based on a question asked against these KB articles. I am looking for guidance to understand the following -

- Are there libraries available (maybe Python) that could allow me to get a potential answer or a set of ranked/scored answers based on a question posed?.

I had a look at IBMs Watson Service and that does a pretty good job, but these articles are not allowed to be interpreted through a cloud service.

PS: I know questions requesting an open-ended guidance are not usually part of StackOverflow's ecosystem, but the domain this question covers is too wide to get a good direction anywhere else.

Comment: Set up a search engine using your KB articles as documents to search and your questions as the query to the search engine.

Comment: We already have a search system but we are trying to work on an interactive system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.
My team at Bluetick Consultants has been working on this since 6 months and we have figured it out. We have tested it on dropbox KB.
Our solution uses multiple python libraries, tensorflow and custom ML models.

Comment: Great to hear that it works. Do you have it publicly documented?. If not, would you be able to share your toolset, broad steps you followed?.

Comment: Not yet public. We want to test it with other KBs as well. I may be able to help on specific problem than complete solution.

Comment: Our use case is - We have KB articles for various internal IT Systems, and we are working on answering questions on these.

Comment: Cool. Please shoot an email to contact@bluetickconsultants.com and someone from my team will reach out to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check cdQA python library which allows you to build custom Closed Domain Question Answering Systems without using the cloud: https://github.com/cdqa-suite/cdQA